# reading parameters and files on browser, looking how to execute on server

Tags: web-development, javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a site done in Rails, which uses javascript to load files and generate forms for the user to input certain information. Those files and parameters are then to be used in a fortran code on the server.

When the UI was on the server (using Qt), I would create a parameters file and execute the fortran code using threads so I wouldn't block the computer.

Now that is web-based, I need to make the server and browser talk. What's the procedure for that? where should I start looking? I'm already using rails + javascript. I need that extra tool to do the talking, and no idea where to start.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer

Comment: if you wanted to make an html button execute the command ls on the server, would you do it with JQuery? I got to JQuery looking for Ajax info

Comment: JQuery is a great JavaScript framework for sending requests to servers from inside the browser. It's industry standard and very easy to use.